# QTPushbutton:hover only working on click

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet, qpushbutton

I am using a stlyesheet to style my qt pushbutton when the mouse moves over it. However, the hover event only fires when I CLICK on the button, nothing happens when I hover my mouse over it

```
Trackbox { background: #FFFFFF;}

 QPushButton {
 position: fixed;
 top: 2px;
 right: 2px;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 }

 QPushButton:hover { background: #c0ffff}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If it makes a difference, I am using QT 5.0.1 and Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 x64 with buttons with the flat modifier.

Comment: Have you set `QPushButton::setMouseTracking(true)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very simple fix. I needed to add a boarder, o px, for hover to work correctly. Thanks for all the help.